# Angular 5 with slick carousel

Tags: html, angular5, carousel, ngfor, slick.js

I am trying to use any carousel in my application, but most of plugins just for images galleries , 
anyone can help me to achieve attached screenshot

thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use [ngx-drag-scroll](https://github.com/bfwg/ngx-drag-scroll)

or [ngx-slideshow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slideshow)